# Compiling Blender as a Python Module Windows

Tags: python, workflow

I'm trying to compile Blender as a python module on my windows machine so I can use an external IDE. In the [tutorial](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) on the blender site. I've tried to follow it, however, the instructions are pretty confusing. The first step says to `copy bin\bpy.pyd C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\`. I can't find the bpy.pyd in the blender directory or the blender source. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the build step in this tutorial. The install part refers to the bpy.pyd you have just built, and can be found in the "blender-git/build" directory. There is a [tutorial](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows) on building blender on windows. Just don't forget the cmake options: WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF, WITH_PLAYER=OFF, WITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON

Comment: How do you change these options with CMake?